# How to draw a correct class diagram?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, uml, class-diagram

I'm working on a project called: Inventory Management System

I just draw a simple class diagram about my project.

My question: is this class diagram correct?

Is (Inventory) class in this position correct?

[image]

Comment: Your notation is definitely wrong. Associations are represented by solid lines, not dotted lines. And the aggregation from Product_Item to Supplier seems wrong from a semantic viewpoint. It feels wrong that a Product_Item would contain (a) Supplier(s). Also Inventory should probably not specialize Person. The Generalization can be read as **is a**. In this case it seems doubtful that an Inventory **is a** Person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make sense to me why you would say that an inventory is a specialication of a person.

Is the aggregation deliberate (did you intend to use composition)?

Having login,register,delete,change in inventory is a smell, these methods have nothing to do with the other three. You even group them together. I would split that class up into three classes to seperate the responsability.

Comment: you can call inventory as the admin of the system so it is a person that has a name, address and phone number. login, register,delete,change have association rules with account class that has username and password.

Comment: but my main question: is class inventory correct that has 4 association relationship ... is this correct in the world of oop